# Getting access to fields in a separate class in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am converting an old app from using a riverpod provider to using a riverpod 2.0 notifier provider. I have converted all of the code but still get an error in one file.

I have a constructor, **UsersNotifier.fromFirestore(Map<String, dynamic> firestore)**, with an initializer list that I need to fix but I am so new to flutter I don't know how.

Every field in the initializer list has an error similar to this error: **'cellPhone' isn't a field in the enclosing class.**

I am calling the fromFirestore from another class here:

```
Users users = Users.fromFirestore(
                          (usersStreamProvider.data! as QuerySnapshot).docs[index]
                              .data() as Map<String, dynamic>);
```

So you can see that I am passing a Map<String, dynamic> to the constructor.

Here is the code for the Notifier class:

```
class UsersNotifier extends Notifier<Users> {
      final firestoreService = FirestoreService();
      final companyRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(('Company'));
      final userDB = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(('users'));
    
    // **************************************************
    
      @override
      Users build() {
        return Users(  // Return the initial state
          userId: '',
          fName: '',
          lName: '',
          address1: '',
          address2: '',
          city: '',
          state: '',
          zipCode: '',
          cellPhone: '',
          officePhone: '',
          email: '',
          companyId: '',
          companyName: '',
          mlsId: '',
          mls: '',
        );
      }  
    
      fromFirestore(Map<String, dynamic> firestore)
          : cellPhone = firestore['cellPhone'],
            address1 = firestore['address1'],
            address2 = firestore['address2'],
            company = firestore['company'],
            companyId = firestore['companyId'],
            userId = firestore['userId'],
            city = firestore['city'],
            fName = firestore['fName'],
            lName = firestore['lName'],
            officePhone = firestore['officePhone'],
            state = firestore['state'],
            zipcode = firestore['zipCode'],
            mls = firestore['mls'],
            mlsId = firestore['mlsId'],
            email = firestore['email'];
      }
    }
```

Here is the Users class which is in the same file:

```
class Users {
  String? userId;
  String? fName;
  String? lName;
  String? address1;
  String? address2;
  String? city;
  String? state;
  String? zipCode;
  String? cellPhone;
  String? officePhone;
  String? email;
  String? companyId;
  String? companyName;
  String? mlsId;
  String? mls;

  Users(
      {this.userId,
      this.fName,
      this.lName,
      this.address1,
      this.address2,
      this.city,
      this.state,
      this.zipCode,
      this.cellPhone,
      this.officePhone,
      this.email,
      this.companyId,
      this.companyName,
      this.mlsId,
      this.mls});

  Users copyWith({
    String? userId,
    String? fName,
    String? lName,
    String? address1,
    String? address2,
    String? city,
    String? state,
    String? zipCode,
    String? cellPhone,
    String? officePhone,
    String? email,
    String? companyId,
    String? companyName,
    String? mlsId,
    String? mls,
  }) {
    return Users(
      fName: fName ?? this.fName,
      lName: lName ?? this.lName,
      address1: address1 ?? this.address1,
      address2: address2 ?? this.address2,
      city: city ?? this.city,
      state: state ?? this.state,
      zipCode: zipCode ?? this.zipCode,
      cellPhone: cellPhone ?? this.cellPhone,
      officePhone: officePhone ?? this.officePhone,
      email: email ?? this.email,
      companyId: companyId ?? this.companyId,
      companyName: companyName ?? this.companyName,
      mlsId: mlsId ?? this.mlsId,
      mls: mls ?? this.mls,
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see I have declared it as a type Users so how do I fix this error and give the constructor access to the Users data fields?

Thanks

Comment: In "fromFirestore" you're not enclosing your variables into your class, that's why

Comment: Thank you. How do I do that? I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

I declared all of the elements in the initialization list like this:

```
    String? userId,
    String? fName,
    String? lName,
    String? address1,
    String? address2,
    String? city,
    String? state,
    String? zipCode,
    String? cellPhone,
    String? officePhone,
    String? email,
    String? companyId,
    String? companyName,
    String? mlsId,
    String? mls,
```

I put this right after the **Users build()**. All of the errors went away but I don't know if this is the correct thing to do.

Is this the correct thing?